# Server and browser date difference

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

When I run my app in browser it shows `last saved just now` or `last saved 2 mins ago` but the problem is the may b different from machine to machine.

Let's say my machine current time is `13:30` and other machine time is `13:34`..
I want this difference..my app is showing in my machine `last saved just now` and in other machine `last saved 4 mins ago`..
I need this difference..any suggestion please?

**UPDATED**
I can get browser time like:

```
var d = new Date();
var hrs = d.getHours();
var min = d.getMinutes();
var sec = d.getSeconds();
if (hrs < 10) {
    hrs = '0' + hrs;
}

if (min < 10) {
    min = '0' + min;
}

if (sec < 10) {
    sec = '0' + sec;
}

var system_date = hrs + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
```

not getting any idea now which time I have to fetch and how?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @choz please see updated quesiton

Comment: Ok, thats javascript. Of course it retrieves client time. Where do you host your app? What i am gettin is that you want to get server time instead

Comment: on IIS..yeah I want server time to get the difference..am I getting something wrong? Need only difference between machine time to original time

Comment: You can retrieve server time on javascript by using ajax. But of course you also have to declare a web method which returns datetime.

Comment: @choz can u provide me demo or example of that?

Comment: I woulda posted it if I could, I am not in that environment til the next 6 hours. But please check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/287430/Calling-ASP-Net-WebMethods-using-jQuery. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is not to use your local computer date. Instead, just return a timespan from the server that indicates how long since the operation occurred. The timespan will be based on the server time.

For example, if you save something at 12:00 on the server-time but your clock is set to 12:05, then if you use the server date of 12:00 and compare it to your local date, 12:05, it will say '5 minutes ago' when it was really instant.

So to fix it, just return from the server a timespan. It could just be number of seconds. Then you can convert it client-side into 'x minutes ago' or 'x seconds ago' or 'x hours ago'.

Alternatively, you could calculate that string on the server and return that to the client.

Comment: I am doing same thing..still it happens..when time comes from server and it compares to system time `function prettyDate(date_str){
 var time_formats = [
 var time = ('' + date_str).replace(/-/g, "/").replace(/[TZ]/g, " "),
        dt = new Date,
        seconds = ((dt - new Date(time)) / 1000),
        token = ' ago',
        i = 0,
        format;` ..still shows `just now` and `4 min ago` in different machine

Comment: Don't use new Date, or any date code that gets the date from the client

Comment: Or alternatively you could return the current datetime from the server and calculate your logic against that rather than using the user's local datetime.

Comment: @dubs thats what I am saying..difference of time between machine and server and will add that difference to the time so it will give appropriate answer..is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
<p>
    Server current time at point of page rendering:
    <input type="text" id="ServerTime" value="@DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s")"/>
</p>

<p>
    My object's date time:
    <input type="text" id="EntityTime" value="@DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(-30).ToString("s")" />
</p>

<div id="Output"></div>


<script>

    var output = document.getElementById("Output");

    var serverTime = Date.parse(document.getElementById("ServerTime").value);
    var entityTime = Date.parse(document.getElementById("EntityTime").value);

    var staticDifference = (serverTime - entityTime) / 1000;

    output.innerHTML += "Static difference between two entities: " + staticDifference + " seconds.<br/>";

    var offset = serverTime - new Date().getTime();

    function calculateDateTime() {
        var commonTime = new Date().getTime() + offset;
        var calculatedDifference = (commonTime - entityTime) / 1000;
        output.innerHTML += "Posted " + calculatedDifference + " seconds ago.<br/>";
    }

    setInterval(calculateDateTime, 3000);

</script>
```